# How to make interface and implementation files separately?

Tags: haskell

I would like to make interface (class, or instance) and implementation files in Haskell separately as follow:

file1: (For interface)

```
class X where
   funcX1 = doFuncX1
   funcX2 = doFuncX2
   ....

instance Y where
   funcY1 = doFuncY1
   funcY2 = doFuncY2
   ...
```

file 2: (For implementation)

```
doFuncX1 = ...
doFuncX2 = ...
doFuncY1 = ...
...
```

How can I do that when file1 must be imported in file2 and vice versa ?

Comment: Especially for class methods, a good question would be: why?

Comment: I want to do that because that way will make my code more clear and concise. Imagine you have many default functions in "class X where", and if you write all of them in the class, it will look like a mess. The more clear way is to make interface and implementation separately. Interface is just to inform the capabilities, don't mix it with its implementation.

Comment: More often than not, a class has very few functions. It's better to redesign your class to have a minimal amount of methods (e.g. for `Control.Monad`, that would be `return` and `(>>=)`), and only introduce methods that *really* benefit from overloading (e.g. `(>>)`). All other functions are just "normal" functions (e.g. `(<<) = flip (>>)`), and a compiler is often much better at optimizing those than you are.

Comment: It makes sense for the class declaration and any general functions defined in terms of it to be in a separate module if you plan on using it more widely, but the instance declaration and its implementation really should be in the same file as each other.

Comment: In Haskell it's sensible to split general from specific but not sensible to split type signatures from functions.

Comment: This question *really* makes me think you're misusing type classes. As a beginner you almost never need to be defining type classes, especially not ones with more than a couple functions defined.

Comment: @Tinctorius What about separating implementation from the interface. For example, in a service-based environment (like WCF in C# or OSGi in Java), where services only export the "interfaces" they implement - and the implementations can be swapped without other modules that depend on them needing a recompile (and sometimes, as in the case of OSGi, it can even be done at runtime).

Comment: @drozzy: Separating interfaces and implementations can be done through the type class system: the class defines the type of the interface, while the instances provide implementations. Every time you use a class constraint, you (might) end up with a dictionary being passed around, which is a similar concept to vtables in C++ and C#. Compile-time swapping is entirely possible, and it's done all the time (most libraries are precompiled, and full of type class constraints). I don't think execution-time swapping is easy in Haskell, even when you've maimed your interfaces to explicitly support it.

Comment: @Tinctorius Thanks, that makes sense. Could you provide an example of compile-time swapping? (I'm just curious!)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any such cumbersome separation in Haskell. Just mark only what you want to be public in the module export list (`module Foo ( X(..) ... ) where ...`), build your project with cabal, and if you want to export a library but not release the source code you can simply publish only the `dist` folder with the binary interface files and the Haddock documentation. That's much more convenient than nasty e.g. `.h` and `.cpp` files that need to be kept manually in sync.

But of course, nothing prevents you from putting implementations in a seperate, non-public file. You just don't need to do "vice versa" imports for this, only perhaps a common file with the necessary data type declarations. E.g.

- `Public.hs`:

  ```
  module Public(module Public.Datatypes) where

  import Public.Datatypes
  import Private.Implementations

  instance X Bar where { funcX1 = implFuncX1; ... }
  ```
- `Public/Datatypes.hs`:

  ```
  module Public.Datatypes where

  data Bar = Bar { ... }
  class X bar where { funcX1 :: ... }
  ```
- `Private/Implementations.hs`:

  ```
  module Private.Implementations(implFuncX1, ...) where

  import Public.Datatypes

  implFuncX1 :: ...
  implFuncX1 = ...
  ```

But usually it would be better to simply put everything in `Public.hs`.

Comment: What if Private.Implementations File still need to import from Datatypes?

Comment: It does (I just forgot to write that `import`), but that's not a problem in any way.

Comment: I really don't think orphaning every instance is something that ought to be encouraged, especially when it serves no particular purpose.

Comment: Just in case the downvote was a reaction to C.A.McCann's comment, I'd like to point out that I did, and do, in no way encourage this orphaning business. I just said it's possible (but also that it's usually better not to do it).